# Shiny Router appending routes

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application, which i have deployed on m a shiny server, the issue right now, is that I'm having trouble.

I have used the quickstart example from the documentation, which so far is working decent.

menu component in the UI

```
menu <- (
  tags$ul(
    tags$li(a(class = "item", href = route_link("/sample-apps/shiny-router/#!/home"), "Home page")),
    tags$li(a(class = "item", href = route_link("side"), "Side page"))
  )
)
```

the problem is that, with the first example id adds `#!` to the beggining of the path

`http://localhost:3838/#!/sample-apps/shiny-router/#!/home`

when the desired output is

`http://localhost:3838/sample-apps/shiny-router/#!/home`

when ever i press the event button it works fine

```
  observeEvent(input$switch_page, {
    if (is_page("home")) {
      change_page("side")
    } else if (is_page("side")) {
      change_page("home")
    }
  })
```

is there a way to mimic this behaviour with the routing menu, so i will just append the route to the current path?

i have tried different solutions, but it seems, that whenever an a tag is clicked it always adds the `#!` prefix to the beginning of the url.

Comment: if I understand correctly the problem is when you try to move to the home page link. Could you please remove the slash (`/`) before the `"/sample-apps/shiny-router/#!/home"`, i.e. change menu to:
`menu <- (
  tags$ul(
    tags$li(a(class = "item", href = route_link("sample-apps/shiny-router/#!/home"), "Home page")),
    tags$li(a(class = "item", href = route_link("side"), "Side page"))
  )
)`

Comment: I figured out the solution but thank you for your comment

Comment: sorry for not being helpful

Comment: no it's all good ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the `route_link` acts like a hash router and therefore the solution would be just to paste the actual string as a path instead of using the route_link solution

```
tags$li(a(class = "item", href = route_link("/sample-apps/shiny-router/#!/home"), "Home page"))

#instead use
tags$li(a(class = "item", href = "/sample-apps/shiny-router/#!/home", "Home page"))
```